# Kernel headers for 3.16.0-rc4-00142-g47ea8dd-dirty cannot be found

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have cloned latest Linux kernel code from git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git. I have build the code using "make" and installed the build-image using "make install".

But, the installation log contains error that it's unable to find kernel headers for the installed kernel.
"Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.16.0-rc4-00142-g47ea8dd-dirty cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-3.16.0-rc4-00142-g47ea8dd-dirty package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located"

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 which has 3.13.0-30-generic headers. I have executed "sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.16.0-rc4-00142-g47ea8dd-dirty" but it's showing "E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.16.0-rc4-00142-g47ea8dd-dirty".
Please suggest what to do to install kernel 3.16.0-rc4-00142-g47ea8dd-dirty headers.

Comment: it's not clear the problem. What is the point? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I was trying to clone latest Linux kernel from Torvalds Git branch, make it and install it. Anyway, I'm able to find out my mistake. I missed the step "make modules_install" before "make install". That was the reason for "E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.16.0-rc4-00142-g47ea8dd-dirty".

Thank you.

Comment: mh probably you did something else. I should not matter the order of  "modules_install"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply follow the steps from this [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/GitKernelBuild) for re-building the kernel on ubuntu. If you have build the kernel as per the above steps you should see the linux-{image,headers}*.deb files created in parent directory. These should be installed using `sudo dpkg -i <path/to/package/name>`
Also you can check why you are getting the `dirty string` appended at the end of the kernel version string. this is possibly due to uncommitted changes or some new files being added.